# Rails Wicked URL routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing, wicked-gem

was curious if there was a way to get the gem `wicked` to have the same url as the starting controller.

So, currently, if I start with the route `www.example.com/customer/new`, then the `wicked` gem sends me to `www.example.com/customer_steps/first`.

But what I would like to have it show is:
`www.example.com/customer/new` route to `www.example.com/customer/first`

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: What's the current route in your routes.rb?

Comment: `resources :customers`
`resources :customer_steps`

Comment: if I have them set to the same routes though, then it gives me a routing error.